# Does the IBM Container Extensions CLI (icecli) have a license?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

The icecli Python package, which [IBM has made publicly available](https://static-ice.ng.bluemix.net/icecli-3.0.zip), does not contain any license information.  Has IBM assigned a license to this package?  If so, what is it?  I personally do not feel comfortable using this package without knowing what my usage rights are.

Answer (score -1):

If you download the package and unzip it, you can find the following:

1. At the README.txt file inside the package:

```
# Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
# (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
# US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
# disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
```

2. At the `PKG-INFO` file you can find `License: UNKNOWN`.

So, I don't think that IBM has used a know license here.